# How to use the counter in a for loop as a part of variable name in R

Tags: r

I have many data.frames named "day01" to "day30" that I have to apply the same code. I can attach the day data.frame before each for loop but it's not practical,
so I want to have something like this in my loop

```
for (i in 1: 30)
{
   tab=day"i"
   #my code
}
```

and even for i 1:9, I want to have 01 ....09 instead of only 1 or 9, so it matches with name of the data frame

and I want also to extract the counter in the same for loop so I can use it in a POSIXct varibale, like "2015-09-i 00:00:00"

Comment: You can put all of your dataframes into a list, then loop over the indices of the list

Comment: sorry i didn't saw your comment. i think it worked for me as i want like in the first answer

Comment: @Mamoud Please ignore the answer and do what the comment said instead. That’s the **proper** answer. The answers below solve the problem, but do so in a roundabout, complex and inefficient way. This isn’t good code.

Comment: but how can i loop throught the list ? i tried `l=list(day01,day02). for (p in l) p$variable[1]=x` but it's wrong

Comment: @CactusWoman, Konrad Rudolph, please guys, if it's so abvious for you, help me please, i wasted very long time replacing every time the name of the next data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `sprintf` to pad your numbers (ie 1 goes to 01) in combination with `get` to turn your character back into the variable:

```
day01 <- 5
day02 <- 6
day03 <- 7
for(i in 1:3){
    tab <- get(paste0("day", sprintf("%02d", i)))
    tab <- tab + 1
    assign(paste0("day", sprintf("%02d", i)), tab)
    print(as.POSIXct(paste0("2015-09-", sprintf("%02d", i), " 00:00:00")))
}
[1] "2015-09-01 EDT"
[1] "2015-09-02 EDT"
[1] "2015-09-03 EDT"
print(c(day01, day02, day03))
[1] 6 7 8
```

Comment: yeah thanks it works :) but now how can i return the tab data frame to the original data frame ? as far the changes are only in the tab table and not yet on the original table

Comment: ok great thanks alot :) i'll try this approch with the second part of my question for the POSIXct variable later, and i'll return to you if i didn't make it

Answer (score 0):

`for(i in 1:30){
  date = sprintf("%02d", i)
  day = paste("day",date,sep="")
}`
You can use the variable `date`from the loop in a POSIXct varibale.